# How to convert a timestamp in Grafana from a formatted string to epoch milliseconds and create a time range URL parameter?

Tags: timestamp, grafana, url-parameters, grafana-loki, grafana-dashboard

I am currently working with Grafana and trying to create a link that redirects to another dashboard with a specified time range, which is 5 minutes before and after a certain timestamp. I have the timestamp details in a formatted string (e.g., "2023-09-20 16:00:20") and I am trying to convert it to epoch milliseconds to use in a URL parameter (like 1695218420000, which seems to be in UTC+02:00).

The time from the log entry is captured in a variable ${__data.fields.Time} which gets substituted into the URL. However, Grafana seems to be unable to interpret the formatted date-time string in the URL parameters for 'from' and 'to' fields to set a correct time range.

For example, using the link structure:
https://localhost:8443/d/XtPc_riIk/fehler-kontrolle?orgId=1&var-hostname=${__data.fields.hostname}&from=${__data.fields.Time:epochmillis-300000}&to=${__data.fields.Time:epochmillis+300000}
translates to:
https://localhost:8443/d/XtPc_riIk/fehler-kontrolle?orgId=1&var-hostname=mrs2-11&from=2023-09-19%2006:55:49&to=2023-09-19%2006:55:49
which is not the correct format for the 'from' and 'to' parameters in Grafana.

I attempted to use the epochmillis function to convert the formatted date-time string to epoch milliseconds directly within the URL, expecting Grafana to be able to interpret and translate it into the correct time range. Additionally, I tried adding and subtracting 300000 milliseconds (5 minutes) to create a time range around the timestamp. However, Grafana seems to not be interpreting the formatted date-time string correctly and is not converting it to epoch milliseconds as expected.

My current Setup:
[image: Dashboard1]

Comment: I don't think you have much options in regards of formatting a field value for use in link. But you can use transformations to add a couple more columns with dates with format and values like you want and use them in link. Probably(?) you can also hide those columns, and still use them in links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @markalex recommended, I employed transformations to introduce additional columns with dates. Regrettably, concealing them disrupts the link functionality, so I have to retain their visibility.

[image: Solution]